# Use variable in a Parse Push message

Tags: variables, push-notification, parse-platform, message, personalization

I really like the Parse push service and integrated it with our CMS. I would like to make the notifications personal by adding the users name in the push message. How can i use a variable (Named 'voornaam' in the screenshot) which is stored in the Installation class in a push message?

[image: Parse data]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something like a message template like

`Hello ${username}, what's up`

sadly its not there. One way you can make the kind of message you want to is by doing it in your server side code before you send the request for PUSH using the REST or other APIs